# Default No in msgbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are there any other products in the carton?", "Question", buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                MessageBox.Show("Please go to the controll room for new packaging", "Message");
                frmHome main = new frmHome(empid);
                main.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

            if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                trans.Commit();
                frmPalletCartonAllocation pca = new frmPalletCartonAllocation(pack, companyIdNo, skuIdNo, UnitsInCarton, UnitsInPack, carton_Code, orderNo, grvIdNo, empid);
                pca.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
```

At the moment when the message box appear the 'Yes' button gets highlighted. I want the 'No' button to get highlighted instead. So default 'No'.

How do I do this?

Comment: I guess it has an overload which takes the MessageBox default Button

Comment: Having `MessageBoxDefaultButton` in your code should be enough of a hint. -1 for not putting in any effort.

Comment: @V4Vendetta he's already using that overload, just needs to change the enum value.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Sorry damn didn't scroll off to the end

Comment: Don't use if... if block instead use if... else if..block since ONLY one condition will be true at a time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change this

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

to this

```
MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
```

Answer (score 17):

change the message box to :

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Are there any other products in the carton?",
    "Question",
    buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2
);
```

Comment: You should always try very hard to put the parent form of the messagebox in the first overload. It you don't the message box can fall behind the form and your app will become frozen on the screen to the user and they will have to kill the app through the task manager...MessageBox.Show(Form....

Answer (score 5):

Change MessageBoxDefaultButton parameter of the method to MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2

Answer (score 0):

`defaultResult MessageBoxResult`

> A MessageBoxResult value that specifies the default result of the message box.

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]
public static System.Windows.MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton button, System.Windows.MessageBoxImage icon, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult defaultResult);
```

SampleCode:

`MessageBox.Show("Message", "Caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Stop, MessageBoxResult.No);`